# Logstash grok pattern to catch the first line with the string Exception

Tags: regex, logstash-grok, grok

This is the an example log:

```
2022-01-07 11:05:01,185 [http-nio-8080-exec-526] WARN  de.web.Main| = - Error while execute Request
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.cg.blart.web.HttpInvocationException: Invalid tenant session
    at com.cg.blume.web.DispatchingServlet.doGet(DispatchingServlet.java:169)
    at de.jinx.lee.web.AutoDBUpgradeDispatchingServlet.lambda$doGet$0(AutoDBUpgradeDispatchingServlet.java:200)
    at de.jinx.lee.web.AutoDBUpgradeDispatchingServlet.addMDCKey(AutoDBUpgradeDispatchingServlet.java:297)
Caused by: com.cg.blume.web.HttpInvocationException: Invalid tenant session
    at com.cg.blume.web.procedure.HttpSessionManager.get(HttpSessionManager.java:190)
    at de.jinx.lee.web.session.leeHttpSessionManager.get(leeHttpSessionManager.java:76)
    ... 41 more
```

This ist the pattern so far:
`^.*?Exception: +%{DATA:exception}$`

The output i get is close but no cigar: `"com.cg.blart.web.HttpInvocationException: Invalid tenant session"`. For the live of me i dont get it to match the whole line. Can you show me the way? The desired output is:
`javax.servlet.ServletException: com.cg.blart.web.HttpInvocationException: Invalid tenant session`

Here is a link for a test tool: https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was this pattern:

```
(?<DATA:mps_exception>.*?(Exception:).*)
```

It is explained here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns